# Android Bottom Navigation - Call action from another navgraph

Tags: navigation, android-bottomnav

I've been struggling with this for a little while now.

I'm using NavigationExtensions.kt with Bottom Navigation in a Java project.

How do I call the action of one navgraph from another navgraph?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I've got a temporary solution where I have added duplicate entries to the required graphs. And it works well.

I've tried out **Global Actions** but they work only with a single graph.

Any better solutions out there?